# MS Project 2007 Start End Date Mismatch

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2007

I have kept the correct start and end date but the duration is getting wrongly calculated.

The start date is 11-June-2015 and end date is 16th -Sept -2015 . They are appearing fine in MPP. But the duration is showing as 291 days which is clearly more than the difference between the start and end dates.

The durations at task level is appearing fine but the overall project level duration appears to be wrong.

[image: Mismatch]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

June 11 2015 to September 16 2015 is 70 working days in duration (excluding Saturday and Sunday).  It appears that you have a Task Calendar assign to the top roll up task - Task 1.  Double click on the task to show the Task Information dialog.  Click the Advanced tab and set the calendar to None.  It will use the calendar set in Project Information.

If you want to roll up the entire project, use the Project Summary task.  Tools, Options, View (I think - it's been a while since I used Project 2007).